# Why is $\int x^n \cos x\,dx$ equal to $\int x^n\, d(\sin x)$?

Tags: integration

I'm sorry, but I cannot understand it. Why is

$\int x^n \cos(x)dx = \int x^n d (\sin(x))?$

Are the notes I have wrong and were they actually meant to be

$\int x^n \cos(x)dx = \int x^n D(\sin(x)) dx$?

Comment: $d(\sin x)$ is just the same as $\cos x\,dx$, just sloppy notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have a function $y = f(x)$. The differential of this function is defined as:

$$dy = f'(x) dx$$

So in your case set $y = \sin(x)$ and you have:

$$d(\sin(x)) = \cos(x) dx$$

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see how that helps. My question was, in English, I hope, is the integral of cos(x) with respect to x the same as the integral of 1 with respect to sin(x)? That is what I should have written above and can't understand.

Comment: If you use the differential and just plug in, it shows that they are equivalent. In essence, both of the statements you wrote are correct. It's just that the second statement has no actual importance.

Comment: It took me a while, but I see it now. Thank you!